# How to convert base64 from email body to string using Robot Framework

Tags: python-3.x, email, robotframework

I get email body from this code.

```
*** Settings ***
Library           ImapLibrary


*** Test Cases ***    
   Email_Verification
       Open Mailbox    host=imap.googlemail.com    user=xxxx@gmail.com    password=xxx
       ${LATEST} =    Wait For Email    sender=xx@email.co.th    timeout=300
       ${HTML}   Get Email Body    ${LATEST}
       Log Many    ${HTML}
       Close Mailbox
```

But the email body display in base64 as below

```
--000000000000b0c6fa05c4db28e0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
4LmD4Lir4Lih4LmI4LiX4LiU4Liq4Lit4LiaDQo=
--000000000000b0c6fa05c4db28e0
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
4LmD4Lir4Lih4LmI4LiX4LiU4Liq4Lit4LiaDQo=
--000000000000b0c6fa05c4db28e0--
```

It's work when email body is English but it's not work when it's Thai

and how to convert the base64 to string or can Get Email Body as Thai

Could anyone please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [evaluate keyword](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluate). You can than work with it as you would in python. Something like this:

```
${string}=    Evaluate    base64.b64decode(${email_body}).decode('utf-8')  modules=base64
```